# Can we have "rhoticized consonant"?

Tags: phonetics, rhoticity

I presume that if your tongue tip is free while you're articulating a consonant, you can make a secondary narrowing with your tongue tip towards the alveolar ridge to produce a double-articulated sound.

- Am I correct?
- If yes, do we have, or has there been a notation to mark it in IPA or other (proposed) phonetic transcriptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[p˞abəbli], if we ever encountered such a thing, we would call it a sequence of consonant plus *r*. However, IPA does have the rhotic hook which could be pressed into service to notate such a thing, if one could argue that you had found a single consonant and not a sequence. Osama Fujimura's CD model does in fact have a richer set of consonants in English, including "rhotic labial" for <pr>. There are no good cases for such a sound.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I was taught was, if I remember correctly, the rhotic hook is only applicable to vowel. Isn't there such a restriction?

Comment: That's not a definition restriction in the IPA, it's more a matter of observation that "rhoticity" only exists for vowels, unless you are speaking of ʈ, ɳ etc. which earn separate letters.